# Python Django for loop not working properly

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have written a simple script, but when I have the loop in the script the `products` and `allbrands` variable comes out empty except when I remove the loop. Here is part of the script.

```
products = amazon.search(Brand="Microsoft", SearchIndex="Software", ResponseGroup="Images,ItemAttributes,Accessories,Reviews,VariationSummary,Variations")
allbrands = Brand.objects.all();
for i, product in enumerate(products):
    print ("Product");
context = {
    'products': products,
    'allbrands': allbrands
}
return render(request, 'storefront/index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`products` is probably an iterator, not an actual list.  Your 'for' loop consumed all of the iterator's items, leaving none to be rendered to your page.  Putting `products = list(products)` after the search() would be one solution - this turns the iterator into a list, which you can then iterate over as many times as you want.